# Measurability of random variable wrt pullback $σ$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Three Polish spaces $A$, $B$ and $R$ are given, and are equipped with their Borel $σ$-algebras $\mathcal B_A$, $\mathcal B_B$ and $\mathcal B_R$. Let $f\colon A \to B$ and $g\colon A \to R$ be $(\mathcal B_A,\mathcal B_B)$- and $(\mathcal B_A,\mathcal B_R)$-measurable functions. Let's write $p(f,g)$ as a shorthand for the following.

*For every Polish space $X$ and all $(\mathcal B_X,\mathcal B_A)$-measurable maps $h,k\colon X\to A$,*
$$f \circ h = f \circ k \implies g \circ h = g \circ k.$$

My question is, is it true that if $p(f,g)$, then $g$ is $(f^{-1}\mathcal B_B,\mathcal B_R)$-measurable?

Here, $\mathcal B_X$ is the Borel $σ$-algebra of $X$ and $f^{-1}\mathcal B_B = \{f^{-1}(B'):B'\in \mathcal B_B\}$ is the usual pullback $σ$-algebra.

---

The idea behind this is that $f$ is a sort of extension of a probability space, in the sense that $B$ is extended by $f$ to $A$ (here I don't consider particular measures, though, and $f$ would have additional properties that I think are unnecessary here). $g$ is a $R$-valued random variable, and $p(f,g)$ sort of states that $g$ is not related to the extension and that $g$ is already available in the smaller space $B$. Actually, this is true if the answer to my question is yes, but I'm not even sure where to start to show that (or to confute it).

Comment: The Doob-Dynkin lemma implies that the property you give is necessary for the measurability of $g$ wrt the pullback algebra. I'm not so sure that it is sufficient. One way to get a counterexample would be to take $g$ to be the identity $A \to A$, and $f$ to be an injective non-strictly measurable map (meaning that the pullback algebra is strictly included in $\mathcal{B}_A$). But I'm not even sure that such maps exist when $A$ and $B$ are Polish.

Comment: You wrote an "$ae$" in there, but never mentioned a measure.  What does it mean?

Comment: You're right. I've rolled it back. However, I believe I need to add measures to make use of it.

Comment: I might have solved the problem. If I have time, I'll write my solution along with the details about the measures.